# Should my CRUD application perform validation on data or should it be a database operation?

Tags: foreign-keys, relational-database, crud

I have a simple CRUD application, using a relational database.

My database has all the foreign keys, unique keys, etc set up.

My question is, should my application perform validation on the input data or should it be a database concern?

For example, imagine a POST, that expect an id for another entity, which is a foreign key in my database.

Is my application supposed to query that id first, see if it is present on the database and, if it's not, return a 404? Or should I simply try to INSERT that entity on the database and wait for a CONSTRAINT error?

Comment: If your CRUD application is a GUI, it's usual to offer a drop-down list for each field of valid values. Your code gets the list by looking up the FK, and that's before there's enough input to validate. (Some development/database tools, like MSAccess, might do some of that for you.) It would be nice to leave all the validation to the DBMS, but usually its error messages are not friendly. Also you might want constraints that can't be expressed as keys/FKs.

Answer (score 0):

After analysing other resources, it looks like I should treat the constraint errors.

It's called `exogenous expressions`. If I validate the data in my application, there may be an unexpected race condition, which another process may change the data that I have just queried.

So, for the sake of consistency, I should catch the database exceptions and do whatever with it.

You can find out more about exogenous expressions [on this Microsoft article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericlippert/vexing-exceptions).

Comment: You can avoid race conditions in your validation code by Commitment Control and/or `READ WITH LOCK`. If any transaction of the application is going to update more than one table, or more than one record, use Commitment Control. That is, get in the habit of using Commitment Control when your application is at the simple CRUD stage, it'll save so much re-engineering later.